# need the sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

This is my query,

```
select a.nvrEquipment as [Equiment Name],a.Availability,b.Breakdown,c.Idle from 
(select nvrEquipment,sum(fltQuantity) as [Availability] from tblEquipment 
where intstatus in(1,2,3) group by nvrEquipment) a left join 
(select nvrEquipment,sum(fltQuantity) as [Breakdown] from tblEquipment 
where intstatus = 2 group by nvrEquipment) b on a.nvrEquipment=b.nvrEquipment left join
(select nvrEquipment,sum(fltQuantity) as [Idle] from tblEquipment 
where intstatus = 3 group by nvrEquipment) c on a.nvrEquipment=c.nvrEquipment
```

I need the another column Utilization in %:

Formula is:

`Utilization in % = (Breakdown + Idle) / Avalilability * 100`

```
Equiment Name  Availability      Breakdown    Idle    Utilization
Crane            3             1            1
```

Comment: DataType for Availability,Breakdown,Idle are integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems pretty straightforward:

```
select a.nvrEquipment as [Equiment Name],a.Availability,b.Breakdown,c.Idle,
(b.Breakdown + c.Idle) * 100 / NULLIF(a.Availability, 0) as Utilization
from 
(select nvrEquipment,sum(fltQuantity) as [Availability] from tblEquipment 
where intstatus in(1,2,3) group by nvrEquipment) a left join 
(select nvrEquipment,sum(fltQuantity) as [Breakdown] from tblEquipment 
where intstatus = 2 group by nvrEquipment) b on a.nvrEquipment=b.nvrEquipment left join
(select nvrEquipment,sum(fltQuantity) as [Idle] from tblEquipment 
where intstatus = 3 group by nvrEquipment) c on a.nvrEquipment=c.nvrEquipment
```

- I multiplied before dividing to obviate INTEGER rounding, if any.
- I used NULLIF to handle division-by-zero.